# Requirements for race that lives close to a sun

Tags: science-based, creature-design, xenobiology

I have an idea for a race that lives on a planet that is extremely close to a sun (similar to ours), just far enough away to not be pulled in.

So my question is, what would be the requirements for a creature on a planet like that to survive such extreme heats without any kind of magic, and without being microscopic either.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the madhouse!  Please check out the [help] and [tour] so that you can get a better idea what kinds of questions we field here and how to go about writing them.  As it stands, a question like this is looking for a (rather!) long list.  List questions are by definition "too broad" and likely to be closed.  WB.SE operates on a "one focused question gets one focused answer" model.  You'll have to edit this question (or delete and start over!) by considering *one specific worldbuilding problem or issue*.

Comment: FYI, any body orbiting a star is constantly pulled in by gravity. There is no minimum safe distance.

Comment: There is no obstacle to living organisms on the surface of the Sun itself given the correct parameters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A planet "just far enough away to not be pulled in" to the Sun will have a surface temperature of just under 5780K. There is no solid material made of atoms at that temperature. You would have a gas giant with a carbon (not carbon dioxide, *carbon*), silicate, and metal vapor atmosphere, and nothing is going to be living on that.

Asking "how close COULD they be to the sun while still existing" is basically the same as asking "what's the highest temperature at which life could exist?" Which is not a question that anyone can answer right now. If you want to know about Earth-like life, based on DNA and proteins dissolved in water and surrounded by lipids, then we *can* answer that--our biochemistry maxes out under 200C. And runaway greenhouse effects combined with the existence of high-pressure exotic phases of ice mean you can't actually have our kind of life on a planet with a surface that hot anyway. Probably the best you could do is have a desert planet with a thin atmosphere a smidge closer to the Sun than Venus.

But if you're looking for extremes, you probably didn't have our kind of life in mind in the first place. And then, well, we just don't know. The highest temperature aliens made of solid/liquid-state baryonic matter that I know of in commercially published fiction are the ones from Hal Clement's *Iceworld*, with body fluids based on molten copper chloride; they exist somewhere between 500 and 900 Celsius (I don't recall if a specific temperature was given in the book), and required solar concentrators to avoid freezing on the dayside of Mercury. That is *incredibly* speculative, but if you just want to copy Hal's idea and assume that they live at the upper end of the liquid range for copper chloride, you could have a planet about with an orbit about 0.773 times as big as Mercury's, or about 0.3AU.

Comment: Maybe worth mentioning that the Hot Jupiter you describe is a [Sudarsky class](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudarsky%27s_gas_giant_classification) 5 type.